# How to persist entities with out defining cascadetype

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

```
I have below two entities.

@Entity
public class ClassA {   

    @JoinColumn
    private ClassA parentA;

    private List<ClassB> classBList;
}

@Entity
public class ClassB{    

    @JoinColumn
    private ClassB parentB;

    @ManyToOne
    private ClassA classA;
}
```

Is it best practice to use cascade ? Cascade will append many classes together which can be a performance hit.

What is the best way to persist ClassA ?
When I want to persist ClassA(It should persist parentA, classBList and in ClassB has parentB which should also gets persisted).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mean, like calling em.persist on ALL objects you want to persist?

Comment: em.persist can be called multiple times too. But I would like to store classB, parentclassB and classBlist and parentA & finally classA. I would like to have all the relations too.. Can you explain how I can do with example code

Comment: why don't you post sample code creating such objects, and then just call persist on all those objects, and see what happens?